# how get into kernel module probe() function when devicetree not present yet

Tags: kernel

when I develope a kernel i2c driver with devicetree . I come across lots inconvenience .

First, I write the driver code with some bugs and I want to debug it when I havent complete the devicetree yet . So because the lack of devicetree I can never trrigger the probe() function so I can not debug the following

THE QUESTION IS : Is there a way to dynamic add devicetree in a running kernel ? Or the method to seperate module development and devicetree development .

In other word . How can I test my driver before devicetree is written ?